# define string macro with escape characters in .pro file QT

Tags: c++, qt, macros, definition

I am trying to define a macro with a string value in the `.pro` file of a QT project like so:

`DEFINES += DRIVESDB=\\\"C:\\users\\grant\\desktop\\log.db\\\"`

In my source files, I would like `DRIVESDB` to equal `C:\\users\\grant\\desktop\\log.db`, however QT spits out errors claiming `\u`, `\g`, `\d`, and `\l` are invalid escape characters. Clearly I am doing something wrong escaping the backslash. Is  it possible to create a string with backslashes in a macro definition? Thanks.

Comment: You can always try slapping more backslashes on it...

Answer (score 1):

Use the forward slash to separate path. Both Qt and Windows understand it.

BTW, Q **T** - is QuickTime, and Q **t** - is a library ))